# Different types of users redirected to same page (index.php) with different content

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I making a PHP class to login the users, based on EMAIL and PASSWORD. I want them to go to the same page (index.php) on login, but showing different content. 
I saw other ACL questions but most of them regarding user escalation, and different group roles.
Here the roles are pretended to be static.

### I have 3 SQL Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `USERS` (
  `userID` int(10) NOT NULL PK AUTOINCREMENT,
  `groupID` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `EMAIL` varchar(99) NOT NULL,
  `PASSWORD` text NOT NULL,
  `regDate` date NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE `SUPPORT` (
  `ID` int(10) NOT NULL PK AUTOINCREMENT,
  `ENGINEERNUMBER` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `EMAIL` varchar(99) NOT NULL,
  `PASSWORD` text NOT NULL,
  `NAME` varchar(99) NOT NULL,
  `OFFICE` varchar(99) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE `CUSTOMER` (
  `ID` int(10) NOT NULL PK AUTOINCREMENT,
  `CITIZENID` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `EMAIL` varchar(99) NOT NULL,
  `PASSWORD` text NOT NULL,
  `NAME` varchar(99) NOT NULL,
  `CITY` varchar(99) NOT NULL,
  `ADDRESS`varchar(99)
)


ALTER TABLE `USERS`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `USERS_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`EMAIL`) REFERENCES `SUPPORT` (`EMAIL`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `USERS_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`EMAIL`) REFERENCES `CUSTOMER` (`EMAIL`),
```

**My DB schema is good? 
Should i have a PHP file, with and if statement, filling index.php with HTML, based on user role?

Thanks in advance, sorry for long post.**

**UPDATE**

```
CREATE TABLE `USERS` (
  `ID` int(10) NOT NULL PK AUTOINCREMENT,
  `NAME` varchar(99) NOT NULL,
  `EMAIL` varchar(99) NOT NULL,
  `PASSWORD` text NOT NULL,
)

CREATE TABLE `TYPES` (
  `ID` int(10) NOT NULL PK AUTOINCREMENT,
  `NAME` int(10) NOT NULL,
)

CREATE TABLE `SUPPORT` (
  `ID` int(10) NOT NULL PK AUTOINCREMENT,
  `USERID` int(10) NOT NULL ,
  `ENGINEERNUMBER` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `OFFICE` varchar(99) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE `CUSTOMER` (
  `ID` int(10) NOT NULL PK AUTOINCREMENT,
  `USERID` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `CITIZENID` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `CITY` varchar(99) NOT NULL,
  `ADDRESS`varchar(99)
)


ALTER TABLE `CUSTOMER`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `CUSTOMER_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`USERID`) REFERENCES `USERS` (`ID`)

ALTER TABLE `SUPPORT`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `SUPPORT_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`USERID`) REFERENCES `USERS` (`ID`)

ALTER TABLE `TYPES`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `TYPES_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`ID`) REFERENCES `USERS` (`TYPEID`)
```

**REVISED DB SCHEMA**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not recommend filling the `index.php` with `if`s and `html` but rather using `if`s and `include` of other `html snippets`.

As for your DB schema you are on the right path but I would change the following.

Leave `name`, `password` and `email` only on the `USER` table. These are common across users, my guess, and you don't want to deal with updating data in multiple places especially for something like password.

You will want to add a `TYPE` or `TYPE` table with an ID and NAME column (make name the same as the table name) and then add a `TYPEID` to `USER` with an `FK`. This way you now know a user is of type SUPPORT or CUSTOMER and can then build a query to find the other info (see below).

Add a column to `SUPPORT` and `CUSTOMER` for `USERID` and make this your FK to `USER` `ID`. The advantage here is that now users can change emails and you know that the `USERID` is unique since it is `PK` of the `USER` table.

You can then query for information like this:

```
//There is an assumption of object here with $user->type.
$query = "SELECT * FROM USER u JOIN {$user->type} t ON u.TYPEID = t.ID WHERE u.ID = ?";
```

As well in your index show the includes like:

```
if($user->type == "SUPPORT"){
    include('path/to/support/template.php');
} elseif($user->type == "CUSTOMER"){
    include('path/to/customer/template.php');
} else {
    //Default catch bad types?
}
```

**UPDATE TO SCHEMA**

```
CREATE TABLE `USERS` (
    `ID` int(10) NOT NULL PK AUTOINCREMENT,
    `TYPEID` int(10) NOT NULL,
    `NAME` varchar(99) NOT NULL,
    `EMAIL` varchar(99) NOT NULL,
    `PASSWORD` text NOT NULL,
)

ALTER TABLE `USERS`
    ADD CONSTRAINT `USERS_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`TYPEID`) REFERENCES `TYPES` (`ID`)
```

Comment: thanks for ur help nerdlyist! below im updating my schema if u can take a look i would appreciatte !

Comment: @JSPinto Close see my edit for the user and type relation.

Comment: ahhhhh thanks! did it the wrong way! the rest is fine right? i'm going to start implementing the login today !

Comment: @JSPinto everything else looks good to me.