# php - Login redirecting to same page, static but different roles

Tags: php, html, sql

After doing my SQL Schema ([Different types of users redirected to same page (index.php) with different content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40306417/different-types-of-users-redirected-to-same-page-index-php-with-different-cont/40307457?noredirect=1#comment67874675_40307457)), I'm starting to make my login system.
I now have this:

```
function login($email,$password){

$mysqli = $this ->dbConnect();
if($mysqli){

    $strQuery = "SELECT USERS.ID, USERS.EMAIL, TYPES.NAME FROM `USERS` LEFT JOIN `TYPES` ON USERS.TYPEID = TYPES.ID WHERE `EMAIL` = '$email' AND `PASSWORD` = '$password'";
    $recordSet = $mysqli->query($strQuery);
    $row = $recordset->fetch_assoc();
    if($recordset->num_rows>0){
        $_SESSION['auth'] = $row['ID']; 
        $_SESSION['username'] = $row['EMAIL'];
        $_SESSION['type'] = $row['NAME'];
        header ("location:"index.php");
        return true;
    }
    //....
}
```

}

Does this look good? Is the query right? Any suggestions for improvement?

**UPDATE**

I have my login working now. And it's redirecting to index.php. But in index php I don't have acess to the $_SESSIONS variables i have stored on my function login. Is there any problem with the attribuitions? Placing the header inside the function not good?
Thanks :)

Comment: Hi. Thre is an error. var `$email` but you defined `$user` in your function. Did you protected your variables from any kind of attacks ?
You used  `table.field` on your request, but you didn't used it on the where part. Normal ? (yes if there is no rick of sharing same fields on both tables). Lat thing: did you use any framework for your bd ? PDO ?

Comment: Thanks :) ! Edited! I'm using mysqli! And no i dont have password hashing and stuff. Just a form with a POST method.

Comment: Ok. No hashing or other stuff to beginw with is ok. But not for a production system (add it later if needed :p) ; DOes not forget to protect your data. Ex: `$post_email = isset($_POST['email']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']) : null;` after `$this->login($post_email, ...)` and finally use something like this `$email = $mysqli->real_escape_string($email);` before using it directly on your SQL

Comment: ahhh! thanks! i really appreciate your help. gonna keep implementing the login adding this changes :)! I'll update later!

Comment: An example of what you talk about (session) ? Did you modified the php code ? What kind of advice did you need now ? :)

Comment: I've updated the question now @GeorgesO. :) Thanks!!

Comment: Ok. **1.** It's better to put the rediction like this: `if( $auth->login('toto', 'titi') ) { Header('Location: index.php'); } else { echo 'Error !'; }`. **2.** If you put a `var_dump($SESSION);` (index.php) did you have any value ? **3.** Do you use `sesion_start()` function (at the beginning of the page)  ?

Comment: Oh. i changed the redirection. I had session_start() on login.php but not on index.php :) . now it var_dumps the session variable. One more question: should i put exit() after all session_start ? i have to have a session_start() in all my pages?

Comment: Use session_start() on all pages with $_SEESION usage :)
Why exit ? You shouldn't use it or only if you know exactly what you need to do.
In your case, after a redirection for example.

Comment: everytime i redirect i should exit()? even if in the redirection i still need the $_SESSION values?

Comment: No. To simplify: **never use** `exit();` 
You should use it only if you does not want the code on the rest of the page to be executed. Otherwize, you can use if/else to do the same thing.
See my complete summarized answer (part 5.)

And to answer: if you redirect, you will be redirected. So the exit() will *never* (some subtilities possible) happend because the code is on the primary page and not in the redirected one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I summarized the previous comments.

**1. Issue: you didn't used the same variables**

`function login($email,$password){` and `$strQuery = " ... WHERE EMAIL = '$email' AND PASSWORD = '$password'";`

**2. Recomendation: use the same namming convention**

On your SQL request you used two way to use fields: `USERS.EMAIL` and `EMAIL =` (with ` arround).
Use the same. This will be easier for later & debugging.

*i.e.*: of course, you should not use `table.field` each time. Not mandatory for example if you have only one table OR if the fields are not shared between them. For my perosnnal usage, I always use this `table.field`. This will prevent any future issue :)

**3. Protect your data from any injection**

Example:

```
$post_email = isset($_POST['email']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']) : null;
```

Alter call

```
$this->login($post_email, ...)
```

And finally use something like this to protect your data:

```
$email = $mysqli->real_escape_string($email);
```

and you are ready for your request:

```
" SELECT [..] FROM users as u [...] WHERE u.email = '$email' "
```

**4. Or use specific functions**

Example (`real_escape_string` not needed anymore):

```
$stmt = $dbConnection->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ? AND password = ?');
$stmt->bind_param('s', $email);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $password);

$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->get_result();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    // do something with $row
}
```

http://php.net/manual/fr/class.mysqli.php

**5. Sessions**

If you want to activate sessions on a spacific page, the **first** code (at the first line) should be `session_start()`.

Calling this method will **activate** the sessions and **load** the $_SESSION variable with content.

```
<?php // index.php
session_start(); // first line

// ... code
var_dump($_SESSION);
?>
```

&

```
<?php // page.php
session_start(); // first line

// ... code
$_SESSION['test'] = time();
Header('Location: index.php');
?>
```

1. Visit index.php -> nothing on the debug
2. Visit page.php -> you will be redirected on index.php
3. On index.php -> you will have data

Enjoy session :p

**6. Handle specific data**

To begin with, you should coose a way to store the credential access (ACL) for each user. For example, store on the database some values as 100001, and each number is a yes/no access for a specific action (binary access mode) ; another system is to store the level '1,2,3,4,5' ... or 'member,customer,admin, ...'. So many ways :)

I will choose the `USER.ACCESS = member|customer|admin` solution

On the **login page**

```
// is user successfully logged
$_SESSION['access'] = $row['access']; // member|customer|admin
// Header('Location: index.php');
```

On any page of your site:

```
if( in_array($_SESSION['access'], ['member', 'admin']) ) {
  echo 'You are a member, you can see this part';
}

if( in_array($_SESSION['access'], ['customer', 'admin']) ) {
  echo 'You are a customer, you can see this part';
}
```

Or

```
if( checkAccess() ) {
  echo 'Welcome user !';

  if( checkAccess(['member', 'customer']) ) {
    echo 'This is a section for member, customer or admin :)';
  }

  if( checkAccess('member') ) {
    echo 'You are a member, you can see this part';
  }

  if( checkAccess('customer') ) {
    echo 'You are a customer, you can see this part';
  }
}

function checkAccess($types = null) {
  if( !isset($_SESSION['access']) )
    return false; // not logged

  if( is_null($types) )
    retun true; // if empty, provide info about loggin.

  // admin has always access to all sections of the website
  $hasAccess = in_array($_SESSION['access'], ((array) $types) + ['admin']);
  return $hasAccess; // user is logged + has accessor not ?
}
```

Of course, you can also use `includes`

```
if( checkAccess('member') ) {
  include 'secret_page_for_member.php';
}
```

Or, at the begening of the included page:

```
<?php
if( !checkAccess('admin') ) {
  return '403 - Not authorized';
  // die('403');
  // throw new Exception('403');
}
// your code
?>
```

Comment: wow! wonderful explanation! i will now put different include(path/to/html) files on my index.php based on the different roles! you helped me a lot @Georges O.

Comment: Another tips: I create a `common.php` page with my session initialization, sql connection and all others configuration variables & stuff. This page is included on all pages of my website.

Comment: thanks! im moving all the content to a .php file now (sql conn etc). What do you think about the if{ include(htmlcontent) ? I've found some people using Js to hide/show content (which i think it's unsecure on this USR lvl approach) and some straight echo 'html content' based on ifs. What is the best approach in your opinion?

Comment: What you you mind ? Display data is the user is connected or not ? Specific data for user/admin or specific roles ? // Yes, JS (display/hide) is unsecure. You should handle this part on the server (php), not the client (js).

Comment: Specific data for admin, other data for manager, and other for customer.

Comment: Use the includes within ifs on index.php?